# How to automatically upload externally changed file without IDE focus

Tags: windows, upload, phpstorm

I know about the automatic upload on external change setting in PHP Storm, but it only happens if PHP Storm is "active / in user focus". So if a file get's changed by some other source and my window focus is e.g. a browser, the file doesn't get uploaded until i refocus the IDE.

Do you know any way how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

'Upload on external change' can't work unless PHPStorm is aware of this change. This is only possible if IDE virtual file system is synchronized with external changes - and it's get synchronized when you move focus to PHPStorm (if 'synchronize files on frame activation' is enabled). To synchronize VFS automatically, you need to run your 'some other source' from PHPStorm (as a file watcher, for example). Otherwise focusing IDE is the only way to make this work

Comment: what's the reason for downvoating?